# How to add string while substituting in %s

Tags: python

My code is below for substituting

```
str_ = 'There is only %s' 
values = (1)
print(str_  %(values))
```

My expected out is

`There is only <test>1</test>`

My output is

`There is only 1`

My code is below

`print(str_  '<test>'+%(values)+'</test>')`  i got SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I dont want the change in the parent `str_`

Comment: Can you give a clear [mre]? And is there a special reason you're using old string formatting and not, let's say, `f-strings`?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on string formatting? Your question indicates that you have misunderstood how it works. Everything except the variable to be formatted into the string should already exist in the format string. This should be covered in any decent tutorial available online. Please do some research before asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Tomerikoo i dont want to change in str_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the string `<test>1</test>` first, *then* fit that into `str_`:

```
>>> str_ = 'There is only %s' 
>>> values = (1,)
>>> print(str_ % ( "<test>%s</test>" % values ))
There is only <test>1</test>
```

Comment: @Nons: `str_` has not been changed here.

Comment: We use `%` twice. Once, to create the argument; the second time, to use that argument with `str_`.

Answer (score 0):

That form of string concatenation only works with string literals:

```
>>> print("hello" "this" "is a test")
hellothisis a test

>>> s = 'something'
>>> print(s "hello" "this" "is a test")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(s "hello" "this" "is a test")
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> # but you can add a comma
>>> print(s, "hello" "this" "is a test")
something hellothisis a test
```

BTW, the form of string interpolation that you are using is mostly outdated. You can use fstrings with a lot more ease:

```
>>> values = 1
>>> str_ = 'There is only' 
>>> print(f'{str_} <test>{values}</test>')
There is only <test>1</test>
```

**Update**

You can do it with a nested fstring, but it's ugly and basically the same as doing old-style string interpolation:

```
>>> values = 1
>>> str_ = 'There is only %s'
>>> print(f'{str_ % f"<test>{values}</test>"}')
There is only <test>1</test>
```

Comment: I think that @chepner has the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65828732/21945) without modifying `str_`.

Comment: @Nons: I have updated my answer. It's not pretty.